# What is the $ in bash?

Tags: bash, dollar-sign

I've been using `bash` for about 3 mounth.
I'm understanding the language step by step but I have a question.
The real significate of `$` in bash is the same of C?

I mean the `$` not `$1`, `$0`, `$#` etc etc.
Only the $.

Comment: In C, there is no `$`, so how could it mean the same?

Comment: @chirlu: it is neither in bash, so theoretically they are the same :)

Comment: Give us some particular context where you found it

Comment: Are you talking about having a '$' for a `PS1` (the prompt)?

Comment: I mean the real significate of only $. Is it only a indicator for the variables? Has it any other significate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$` is used to perform parameter expansion. For a variable named `foo`, the expression `$foo` expands to the value of the variable.

```
$ foo=3
$ echo "foo"
foo
$ echo "$foo"
3
```

`$` is also used as the default/generic prompt, but there it is simply used as a distinctive character; it has no actual meaning, and could be replaced without causing any change in functionality.